# How can i bulk insert into a table in h2 database?

Tags: h2, bulkinsert

I have a table in h2 database on which i want to perform a BULK INSERT, as we do in SQL server

How can I achieve this in h2 database?

Comment: What does this BULK INSERT do?

Comment: `String sql = "BULK INSERT "+tableName+" FROM '"+fileName+"' WITH (DATAFILETYPE = 'char',FIELDTERMINATOR = '"+separator+"',ROWTERMINATOR = '\r\n', KEEPNULLS );` where filename is(test.backtickcsv) , It will load multiple rows of data. @a_horse_with_no_name